# Python & requests | ImportError: No module named util

Tags: python-2.7, pip, python-requests

I just installed the package requests on a new computer. I'm getting this error when I try to import that module. Any ideas what's causing the issue w/ the util module?

```
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 

[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import requests

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  from . import utils
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
  from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
  from .packages import chardet
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  from . import urllib3
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  from .connectionpool import (
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 36, in <module>
  from .connection import (
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 43, in <module>
  from .util import (
ImportError: No module named util
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

on pypi.python.org I see, that latest version of `requests` is 2.2.1

Your listing shows, you have installed version 2.3.0, so it is likely, you are using development version which is not yet really completed.

Uninstal it:

```
$ pip uninstall requests
```

And install production quality one:

```
$ pip install requests
```

In case, it would still mess up with version 2.3.0, install explicitly the 2.2.1

```
$ pip install requests==2.2.1
```

Comment: I just tried `sudo pip uninstall requests` and it seemed to go well.I tried installing exactly 2.2.1 and got the same error, so I re-removed requests and  tried a test of `import requests` and got the same error.

`ImportError: No module named util`

Comment: @user3195487 This is strange. Can you test it using virtualenv? This shall provide very clean environment for such a test.

Comment: @user3195487 When you do `$ pip freeze|grep requests`, what version of requests is shown there?

Comment: I figured out the issue. i had installed requests without using pip so I had to manually remove it. Just tried to install pip with your advice and it worked great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3195487 Great. Learn using `pip` even for installing development packages - it is very powerful tool, allows installing from pypi, eggs, wheels, from local source directories, from git... And it finally become part of Python in 3.4

Comment: yeah, I'm definitely new to python, unix and pip. Should I always be installing packages w/ `sudo pip install packageName`? or is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: @user3195487 We are getting off track. But last recommendation is: install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`. `virtualenv` comes with `pip` installed and allows you to create any number of well isolated development environments. `virtualenvwrapper` gives you a commands like `workon` which switch to diferent environemnts.

Comment: Cool, I'll play around with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51779/discussion-between-jan-vlcinsky-and-user3195487)

Answer (score 0):

As seen here [Bug 1459100](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1459100)
I have do execute the following commands:

```
# mv /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests_old
```

then

```
dnf install python-requests --best --allowerasing
```

So, finally I can start virt-manager again.

My system specs:
**Fedora 25**

```
$ /usr/lib/

python2.7/ python3.5/
```